# Facebook - How to get the comments of a fb:comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to get the comments posted on a fb:comments widget. Here is what I've tried:

http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id={{ url_of_the_page }} - Returns an empty list

Executing the following FQL

SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time 
FROM comment 
WHERE object_id IN 
  (SELECT comments_fbid 
   FROM link_stat 
   WHERE url ={{ page_url }}) - Return an empty response with the fql header

I'm beginning to think that this is not possible. Am I missing something or is this indeed not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how you do it.  What is the url you are trying?  For example, this random Techcrunch article works in the same way as you describe:
http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http://techcrunch.com/2011/09/20/digg-experiments-with-topic-newsrooms-aggregates-news-by-most-meaningful-stories/

Comment: I think I figured it out. For some reason the particular url that I was trying to use was not being handled very well by the FB API so I encoded it and now it works like a charm. Thanks for confirming the API call.